# List running instances of jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Jupyter notebook comes with the useful command:

```
jupyter notebook list
```

which outputs all the running server instances for the current user. Besides it lists the relevant access tokens.

Jupyter lab seems not to have this feature.

Cruising through the `jupyter lab` manual I could not find the analogous command (not the analogous syntax seems to work).

Any suggestion on how to get ports and tokens for the running servers?

Comment: With a Jupyter notebook's Code cell, try run `!jupyter notebook list`.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Comment: I really need this too, is there an official way to do this? `jupyter notebook list` seems to work in some cases (e.g. global installs) but not from a poetry-managed venv.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using JupyterLab 3.0+, the command you're looking for is:

```
jupyter server list
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems like you can still call `jupyter notebook list` within any terminal to list all the running notebook instances, including those within jupyter lab.

Comment: Not in my case... list shows empty... maybe different versions? I'm sure however that the server is running. Thanks though.

Comment: @Acorbe I'm running jupyter==1.0.0  and jupyterlab==0.31.12 as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

One can now use the `list` command with Jupyter lab to show running servers:

```
jupyter lab list
```

If you want to list the associated sessions for that server there doesn't appear to be built-in command but (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5013)) you can run this to a get prettified (with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) JSON list using the [Jupyter REST API](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/rest-api.html) - assuming your server runs at `localhost:8888` and :

```
curl -sSLG localhost:8888/api/sessions --data-urlencode `jupyter lab list | awk '/token/ {split($1,a,"?")} END {print a[2]}'`  | jq
```